# differences between appgyver Steroids and appgyver Supersonic

Tags: cordova, steroids, appgyver, supersonic

I am looking for some differences between the steroids and supersonic. I read that supersonic is based on steroids but I can't find more big differences. Both support some cloud tooling.

If supersonic is kind of "better Steroids", will Steroids project be less supported?

Does any of these support local build also? Building in the cloud is kind of risky in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different project types right now when you use the command line interface with Appgyver. If you want to build a single page application, you will not have Angular included in your project. If you build with the multi page application option, Angular is the javascript framework of choice. You can use your own framework if needed on both types. Here is a piece of the documentation on creating a new project:

> Note: Even though we recommend using Angular, Supersonic is framework agnostic. If you prefer a different framework, choose Single-Page application when prompted for application type, and create the app structure yourself.

Those are the main differences. Supersonic handles the view push/pull/transitions to make it look and feel like a native application. Lots of native functionality is wrapped in Supersonic methods.

It is worth reading in the [docs](http://docs.appgyver.com/supersonic/guides/) to learn a bit more about this.

The projects are deployed to the Appgyver cloud where you can choose to create builds for Android and iOS separately with a great interface for adding your icons and splashscreens as well as plugins.

There is no local build option that I have seen with this product. One nice feature is the simulator build which allows you to run the simulator with any plugins you've included in your build.

Overall, I have had a good experience developing with this product for over a year now. I was able to get an app in the Apple Store in little time, and with the help of the build service documentation. This has made the process easy.

I'd recommend trying it out. The [forum](http://community.appgyver.com) is getting more attention and is very helpful.